# How to show and add toolbar buttons to UITableViewController with Swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitoolbar

I am trying to programatically show and add toolbar buttons to a toolbar in a UITableViewController embedded in a UINavigationController.  The toolbar appears but no buttons appear.  Here is my code:

```
    var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
    items.append(UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil))
    items.append(UIBarButtonItem(title: "Clear", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("btnClearAction")))

    self.navigationController!.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)
    self.navigationController!.setToolbarItems(items, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

While migrating my app to swift, I just found out I had the same issue. Only I'm trying to add it to a left menu controller which holds a table view. Shouldn't be all that different?

I just now got it solved by creating the toolbar programmatically.

Here's what I did:

Under the class

```
class LeftViewController: ViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
var tableView: UITableView!
var toolBar: UIToolbar!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 45/255, green: 45/255, blue: 45/255, alpha: 1.0)

    self.tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style: .Plain)
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)

    //UPDATE #3
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-20)
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None


    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true

    let Button1 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button1", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "your action")
    let Button2 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button2", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "your action")
    let Button3 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button3", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "your action")
    let Button4 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button4", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "your action")

    //Flexiable Space
    let flexiableItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)


    //UPDATE #2
    toolbarItems = [Button1, Button2, flexiableItem, Button3, Button4]
}
```

Obviously style your buttons, view, cells etc..however you want.

I did leave a lot out of what I posted because it didn't pertain to the topic.

Hope this helps.

UPDATE:
Awesome. One fix brings on another problem.
My toolbar vanishes when rotating the device. Rotate back and the buttons are gone. Could just be something in my project but yah.

UPDATE #2:
Answer updated with working code. Removed the toolBar I made and found a solution which works. Even with rotation.

UPDATE #3:
Sets the table view 20px creating a "status bar" and reduces the bottom of the table view by 20px so it fits on top of the toolbar.

Comment: Thx but navigation controllers have built in toolbars so I don't think this solution makes sense.

Comment: If you happened to read UPDATE #2, you will see that I did away with that toolbar I created and used the standard toolbarItems. Which points it to the navigationController toolbar.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't see that.  Thx. I'll check out after turkey day.